# Eclipse starting multiple instances of simulator

Tags: eclipse, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I have eclipse with blackberry plugin. When my eclipse kept idle for some time it starts the blackberry simulators automatically. I then I have close eclipse then only it stops otherwise it goes on....

Is there a way to avoid this ?

Thanks,
nil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

such problems never occurred with me even I am working since couple of years. it might be some kind of unusual. Reinstall your blackberry jde plugin and check.
by the way what os and which version of jde and simulator your using?